# Ordenar una tabla sin sql dinamico

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de ordenar una tabla sin sql dinamico para un datatable en jquery, el datatable de jquery manda el valor de @ORDEN al sql y devuelve los datos al datatable en el orden que eligió.

Este es mi query

```
DECLARE @ORDEN NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Nombre ASC';
SELECT
   TOP (1000) [Id],
   [Nombre] 
FROM
   [Prueba].[dbo].[tblPrueba] 
ORDER BY
   CONVERT(SYSNAME, @ORDEN)
```

Yo estoy tratando de hacerlo sin sql dinamico o case porque serian demasiados case en algunas tablas que tengo

Comment: Sin SQL dinámico y sin usar CASE es prácticamente imposible. Sería mejor que nos expliques que quieres hacer.

Comment: primero que nada, para qué necesitas ordenar?